# Accuracy function in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I Want to compute the accuracy of a numerical vector that contains 12 forecasts but I get this result with a warning.

```
`> accuracy(f,Test)
                    ME      RMSE       MAE       MPE      MAPE ACF1 Theil's U
Training set       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NA        NA
Test set     0.9064933 0.9064933 0.9064933 0.4060658 0.4060658   NA        NA
Warning message:
In trainingaccuracy(f, test, d, D) : test elements must be within sample`
```

Test :

```
`Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul
2012 223.23801 203.51890 195.21139 169.68900 157.63439 135.79616  96.84895
           Aug       Sep       Oct       Nov       Dec
2012 100.42089  62.51129  49.18672  22.10280   5.00000`
```

I get f by this code :

```
`f  <- list()
for (i in 1:12) { 
  demfit <- ets(Dem2) 
  f[[i]] <- forecast(demfit, 1)  #start filling the f list with values
  Dem2[length(Dem2)+1] <- f[[1]]$mean[1]
} 
f <- unlist(f)`
```

This code aim to get one-step ahead forecasts 12 times ( at each time, I update my serie by the forecast value)

Thank you for your help

Comment: I was just reading the documentation of `accuracy` and noticed that the second argument of the `accuracy` function is `x`. The third argument is actually `test`. So can you try: `accuracy(f, test=Test)` ?

Comment: I think It's the same thing, but if you look at the output of accuracy, there isn't MASE measure

Comment: Can you give an example of `Dem2` so we can run the code?

Comment: Dem2 : 

`[1] 514.4378 508.0725 505.1332 486.0062 482.2012 470.3746 447.3068 438.8316
 [9] 415.9165 408.4435 409.6771 395.5217 394.9384 381.1989 381.9465 363.3864
[17] 361.5023 352.9679 334.8661 340.4177 326.4133 331.1433 337.0790 336.5174
[25] 336.1014 320.4492 324.1038 311.1634 303.7870 305.8036 285.1999 297.9509
[33] 274.9366 272.9125 268.5839 271.3597 260.8548 258.7807 271.4334 271.4318
[41] 267.4684 271.7790 254.8372 266.9153 242.4234 241.0491 230.2998 233.5749`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem by doing this code :

`fl<-structure(list(mean=K,x=Dem2,fitted=f1$fitted),class="forecast")`

It creates an object from the class "forecast" which contains the necessary element to compute measure MASE.

Thank you